# Marker new postion created but old is also showing in ajax google map

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi i'm trying to get markers latlon from ajax, i m getting ajax data every second and also able to create marker within radius , now i'm facing problem with updating marker positions as in current new marker created and old one also showing. Pls help to update markers which i am getting from ajax and remove extra.

```
    var map = null;
var geocoder = null;
var markers = {};
var infoWindow = null;
var minZoomLevel = 16;

jQuery('#search').click(function() {
    var address = jQuery('#address').val() || 'India';
    if (map === null)
        initializeMap();
    searchAddress(address);
});

function initializeMap() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: minZoomLevel,
        draggable: true,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        scrollwheel: true,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);     
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
             initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
             map.setCenter(initialLocation);
             // Limit the zoom level
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
     if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
 });
         });
     }
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function(event) {
        searchStoresBounds();
    });
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
}


function searchAddress(address) {
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
            map.setCenter(latlng);
                         // Limit the zoom level
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
     if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
 });
            searchStoresBounds();

        } else {
            alert('Geocode was failed: ' + status);
        }
    });
}


setInterval(function searchStoresBounds() {
    var bounds = map.getCenter().toUrlValue();
    var url = './store.php';
    var parameter = { bounds: bounds };
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: parameter,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: showStores
    });
}, 1000);


function showStores(data, status, xhr) {
    if (data['status'] != 'OK')
        return;

    var id;

    // add markers for new stores
    for (id in data['data']) {
        if (markers[id] === undefined)
            createMarker(id, data['data'][id]);
    }

    var b = map.getBounds();
    // remove markers out of the bounds
    for (id in markers) {
        if (! b.contains(markers[id].getPosition())) {
            markers[id].setMap(null);
            delete markers[id];
        }else{createMarker(id, data['data'][id]);}
    }
}

function createMarker(id, store) {

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                parseFloat(store['lat']),
                parseFloat(store['lng'])
            );
    var html = "<b>" + store['address'] + "</b>";
    var x = store['distance'];

        var y = 1000;
        var z = x * y;
    var m = 85;
    var t = z / m;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Math.ceil(t);
       var headm = store['bearing'];
       var car = "M17.402,0H5.643C2.526,0,0,3.467,0,6.584v34.804c0,3.116,2.526,5.644,5.643,5.644h11.759c3.116,0,5.644-

2.527,5.644-5.644 V6.584C23.044,3.467,20.518,0,17.402,0z M22.057,14.188v11.665l-2.729,0.351v-4.806L22.057,14.188z 

M20.625,10.773 c-1.016,3.9-2.219,8.51-2.219,8.51H4.638l-2.222-8.51C2.417,10.773,11.3,7.755,20.625,10.773z 

M3.748,21.713v4.492l-2.73-0.349 V14.502L3.748,21.713z M1.018,37.938V27.579l2.73,0.343v8.196L1.018,37.938z 

M2.575,40.882l2.218-3.336h13.771l2.219,3.336H2.575z M19.328,35.805v-7.872l2.729-0.355v10.048L19.328,35.805z";
var icon = {
    path: car,
    scale: .7,
    strokeColor: 'White',
    strokeWeight: .4,
    fillOpacity: 1,
    fillColor: '#333333',
    offset: '5%',
    rotation: parseInt(headm),
    // rotation: parseInt(heading[i]),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 25) // orig 10,50 back of car, 10,0 front of car, 10,25 center of car
};
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: latlng,
            icon: icon,

        });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(html);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    markers[id] = marker;
}
```

Comment: Hi i am new and dont know much about how to ask question so pls ignor if any mistake thanks

Comment: declare var marker; globally and then in the showStores function at the 1st line write marker.setMap(null);

Comment: dear all marker gone, i want to show markers position updated from ajax but your solution removes all, pls help

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the issue due to this part

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng,
        icon: icon,

    });
```

Everytime you get data from ajax it creates a new marker.

Add the following declaration at the top of your js page

```
var marker;
```

and change the marker creation to the following

```
if(marker)
{
   marker.setMap(null);
}
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng,
        icon: icon,
   });
```

Before you create a new marker the previous one is removed from the map. The if(marker) part is needed to check if a marker instance has been created because the first time that you run there will be no marker and you will get an error while trying to remove the marker.

**Edit 1 :**

As you have multiple markers you will need to store an array of markers and remove them before adding new markers on map

At the top of the page you will need to declare

```
var markerArray = new Array();
```

Just before you add the markers you will need to clear the previous markers

```
for(var i = 0; i<markerArray.length; i++)
{
   markerArray[i].setMap(null);
}
markerArray = new Array()
```

After that will be your current code

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng,
        icon: icon,
   });

markerArray.push(marker);
```

You will need to add the marker to the markerArray so that it can be cleared the next time your code executes.

Comment: Dear it helps to update marker every second but problem is that my ajax getting two markers form database and your solution only showing 1 from array. pls help me to show all markers in array except only one thanks

Comment: dear i am getting below array from ajax:

Comment: {"status":"OK","data":[{"id":"2","lat":"22.613524","lng":"88.331837","address":"Howrah, India","bearing":"65","distance":"0.6372757297353733"},{"id":"3","lat":"22.614347896817133","lng":"88.3255072245788","address":"Liluah, West Bengal, India","bearing":"320","distance":"0.5282461028898005"}]}

Comment: Dear i need to show all array getting from ajax  and update marker position per seconds thanks

Comment: dear joyson pls help me out to echo all as when i use var marker it shows all but not update pls help

Comment: still facing same issue:

Comment: Only first array showing from ajax, can u post it in jsfiddel or here entire to achive what i want, pls thanks

Comment: Can you add the code in jsfiddle, i'll edit it there.